# Access Query Issue (SQL)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to pull some totals and having an issue with it recognizing all my records. Here is my current code:

```
SELECT Contacts.[Date Added], Count(Contacts.[Customer Last Name]) AS   [Records Per Day], (Round(45000)-Count([Customer Last Name]))\(Count([Date Added]<=Date())) AS [Days Till Completion], Count(*) AS Expr1
FROM Contacts
WHERE (((Contacts.[Date Added])>=Date()-1))
GROUP BY Contacts.[Date Added];
```

Currently it is showing how many many records were entered per day (which I need) but it won't show how many records are in the table total. If I separate the queries I can get them to work individually but I cannot combine them. I need this info so I can build a report showing all of this data and I've tried to build a report using the two different queries but it won't work either. 
Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you can't get all the records and have a where clause..  a where clause LIMITS your results, so you will not get "ALL records"  (thus you can't count what you've omitted through a where clause) you need to conditionally count (sum) the records using a `case` or `iif` (I don't think access uses case) statement instead of using a where clause.

Comment: You can try to use a subquery for this.

Comment: I think you should add some more `(` and `)`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some sort of sub query. [Here are more types.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa217680(v=office.11).aspx)

```
   SELECT Contacts.[Date Added]
    , Count(Contacts.[Customer Last Name]) AS   [Records Per Day]
    , (Round(45000)-Count([Customer Last Name]))\(Count([Date Added]<=Date())) AS [Days Till Completion]
    , Count(*) AS Expr1
    , (Select count(*) from Contacts where ((Contacts.[Date Added])>=Date()-1)) as TotalCount 
    FROM Contacts
    WHERE (((Contacts.[Date Added])>=Date()-1))
    GROUP BY Contacts.[Date Added];
```

Comment: Okay I'll give that a try. I've had issues adding a sub query before. Keeps saying I can't pull two query's into one. But I'm checking out your link right now to see what I can learn. Thanks!!

Comment: I was being dumb (Holiday's have me working without thinking). I've added a sub query and that fixed all my problems :-) Thanks for the help everyone!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can build your query based on this example:

```
WITH GROUPS AS (
SELECT 'a' item ,222 total
UNION
SELECT 'b' item ,778 total
)
select item, total ,(select sum(total) from GROUPS) as grand_total
from GROUPS
```

in your case "GROUPS" is the original query you wrote, and total is your "Records Per Day" field.